# I have Hubspot but we are migrating to Account Engagement. I have several Contact Lists that need to upload into Account Engagement

Tags: account, upload

I have several Contact Lists that need to upload into Account Engagement from Hubspot. I know that I can create static lists and import the contact lists into Pardot, but my concern is related to the overall contact/lead database in SF.
If I upload those lists and assign them to a user, group or queue, would those be sync with a contact record or lead record if their email address match in the CRM?